# If an object parse it's own input, is it considered breaking SRP?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

If an object parse it's own input, is it considered breaking SRP?

For example

```
class A
{
    int x;
    string y;
    float f;
    A(string x, string y, string f)
    {
        this.x = int.Parse(x);
        if (this.x < 0 || this.x > 10)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        this.y = y;
        this.f = float.Parse(f);
    }
}
```

Or to have a private constructor and use a public static method that parse and checks input and return `A`.

Instead of passing an int, string and float and parsing and checking if they're valid somewhere else.

Comment: IMO your constructor should take the correct types, and not be doing any parsing.

Comment: What about a public static method that does the parsing and creates the object? @MatthewWatson

Comment: That would be better, because you can give it a more descriptive name rather than it just being the constructor. But it still seems to me that the responsibility of parsing strings into floats and ints belongs in the area of code that is obtaining those strings, or in some class inbetween.

Comment: The constructor has 1 responsibility, to construct the object, if parsing is required to do this, IMO, it's fine, because it has only one responsibility. If the data changes for any reason, it still only has one responsibility. One thing to note, the parse may throw an exception, and you have no exception handling at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it breaking single responsibility principle? No, the example given you are parsing primitive types, to construct a basic object, I don't feel in the example code you've given that it's a responsibility in it's own right. SRP is easier to explain given a business domain to operate within...

To elaborate, parsing as used above is working on primitive data types, the built in parsing on primitive types serves to facilitate conversion of one primitive type to another. The purpose of SRP is not to abstract such core functionality, but to ensure that the design of your code has a single responsibility. For example, when saving a record to the database, you could write a function that picks up the raw data, maps it to the different tables and sends an email to confirm the entry, this is breaking SRP. How do we avoid this in such an example? Using things such as the repository pattern to abstract away the database concerns, having a separate class to manage email communications, perhaps using dependency injection to ensure that these components are readily interchangeable in your solution. Would I seriously try and abstract all basic parsing on primitive types?

Absolutely not.

Underpinning the whole concept is the "reason to change", if your code design has more than one reason it would have to change, it's breaking SRP. In the example given, if the email changed, or the raw data, or the mapping to different tables, we'd need to change the code, for 3+ different reasons.

That being said, your constructor or functions should ideally accept the correct type, there may be reasons as to why you cannot do this, but you should avoid parsing if you can supply the values in the right type.

One last thing to add: I've seen many developers get hung up on issues such as this relating to primitive types, parsing and constructing objects, attempting to ensure no design principles might be broken, such as SRP. They have spent hours meticulously looking at issues and missed much larger domain design problems as a result. Try to ensure you can see the bigger picture and you don't lose sight of your application architecture. I'm not suggesting you never worry about such things, just don't fall into the trap of missing the bigger problems in designing your applications.

Comment: I do not mean to be rude, but I'm astonished that this non-sense have a positive score. "low level operations like parsing are more to do with management of your data and variables than application behaviour" ... that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this then? @plalx

Comment: Well, you succeeded in being rude @plalx. SRP is more to do with the functionality of your application, and the design of the domain it is operating in. C# is a high level language, generally speaking, and parsing is one of the lowest level operations available. Should you allow such operations to complicate your solution and muddy the waters of a good domain driven design, when they are ubiquitous in the language? No, you should not.

Answer (score 3):

If we agree that parsing is a responsibility (because it introduces an axis of change related to the data format) then the only question is whether `class A` has another responsibility. If `class A` has additional logic unrelated to parsing, that would indicate another responsibility.

It is interesting to consider that `class A` is already both parsing and validating its input. The validation may be a second axis of change, related to business requirements. Is this violating SRP? That depends on how likely we think it is that these two axes will vary independently.

Comment: This is a more concise answer than mine, and one I'd agree with